# What kind of clothing was worn in Mahgreb states circa the high medieval period?

Tags: middle-ages, clothing, fashion, north-africa

I'm interested in medieval clothing (I'd focus on the time period from the 9th century onwards) in north Africa especially in the Maghreb states and the other countries that surround the Sahara such as Mali, Senegal etc..

I made some search but couldn't find more than pages of this kind
[North Africa history of dress](https://womens-fashion.lovetoknow.com/womens-fashion-history/north-africa-history-dress)

which hardly satisfy my need in this regard!

However among my search results were also Auguste Racinet's books:

- "[The Costume History](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3836555409)" and
- ["The Complete Costume History](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3822821934)".

If anybody could provide some information whether I'll find what I want there it would be great.

I would like to pursue the changes in fashion and costumes over this period of time.  I'd be interested in all typical kinds of clothes be it for everyday life or special occasions such as marriages, festivals and also court and alike.  Also the clothing based on costume conventions like, gender, class,  ethnic or religious affiliation etc.  is of interest.

I'd also be happy to get some sources where I can find some more or less detailed description of the clothing.

Comment: Aside,  to the community.  Seems like there should be a more precise word for the set of inhabitants that include both Jews and slaves - the set of people who are frequently distinguished by norms and conventions of costume.  Is there such a term in the study of costume history? costume conventions would seem to normally vary by class, gender, etc, but also by subcommunity.

Comment: @MCW The German term would be [Stände](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A4ndeordnung). (I seem to actually remember reading the term "ständische Kleidung".) The WP article [Estates of the realm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estates_of_the_realm#Dynamics) cites Johan Huizinga with a definition of "estate" that reads a bit like a listing of every group that wears distinct clothes. He [talks](https://www.dbnl.org/tekst/huiz003verz04_01/huiz003verz04_01_0005.php) (p.67, in Dutch) of "stand" and relates them to the  latin terms "estat" and "ordo".

Answer (score 3):

*sources only; I'm not qualified to answer, but I asked my professional historian/costumer for advice.*

- [Arab Dress a Short History: From the Dawn of Islam to Modern Times](https://a.co/d/iDqyVzr) (THEMES IN ISLAMIC STUDIES)
- [Women's Costume of the Near and Middle East](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0043910114)
- [Costume Society of America](https://costumesocietyamerica.com/); they won't have the answer, but can point to additional resources.

FWIW, we still haven't found a clear, useful term for communities of unconventional costumes. Stande sounds good, but sounds class oriented, and might ignore ethnic and gender communities.